# Are there any alternatives to FastSharp?

Tags: c#, code-snippets

Are there any alternatives to Matt Manela's [FastSharp](http://blogs.msdn.com/matt/archive/2008/02/11/fastsharp-write-it-execute-it.aspx) tool? I have a vague recollection that there was at least one alternative.

Here FastSharp is the [download link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FastSharp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)
2. [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (by Joseph Albahari, author of C# 3.0 in a Nutshell) - definitely worth checking out, can connect to a DB and try out some LINQ to SQL etc.
3. [Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) (by Jon Skeet, used for demos in his C# in Depth book) - apparently also has an [add-in for Reflector](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/11/23/the-snippy-reflector-add-in.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)?